# What am I missing with my ul className function call

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, components

Not sure if I'm using the correct function in the ul list class.

```
export default () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="nav-center">
        <div className="nav-header">
          <Link to="/">
            <img src={logo} alt="Beach Resort" />
          </Link>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="nav-btn"
            onClick={() => setIsOpen({ isOpen: !isOpen })}
          >
            <FaAlignRight className="nav-icon" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <ul className={isOpen ? "nav-links show-nav" : "nav-links"}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/rooms">Rooms</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

I want the classNames to toggle based on the toggle function.

Comment: You set isOpen initially to a boolean and later set it to an object `if({isOpen:anyting})` is always true. You can toggle isOpen like so: `onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}`

Answer (score 1):

You dont set an object like in class like components, rather you just set value direct in case of using hooks

```
<button type="button" className='nav-btn' onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
```